# ¿ayuda con str_replace, y multiples cambio?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy creando una pagina, donde el usuario registre y comparta contenido, pero me gustaría usar texto en **títulos en negrita** y eliminar palabras obscenas, pero sin usar las típicas etiquetas, así como esta pagina que ofrece ** para **negrita** entre otras, esto lo hago con el fin de evitar almacenar en la BD, etiquetas html, así que si alguien sabe como funciona esa herramienta me podrían ayudar.

he buscado información y solo consigo `str_replace()` pero con esa función en php logro cambiar todos los `*` por `<b>` y no se como hacer para que me reemplace el siguiente `*` por `</b>`

Comment: Por favor lee [ask], tu pregunta es amplia, poco clara y basada en opiniones, si editas muestras tu avance y dudas claras sería distinto

Comment: Hola puedes descargar y usar la librería [Parsedown para Markdown](https://parsedown.org/) es muy fácil de utilizar en las páginas php, de modo que recoges texto plano escrito usando markdown y lo muestras como html. Y, en caso de querer usar tablas y marcadores posicionales puedes usar [php MarkDown Extra](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/). Yo las empleo con éxito en mis sitios.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo puedes conseguir con la función `preg_replace()` con una expresión regular con un *grupo de captura* con *cuantificador perezoso*, y usando *referencia anterior* para el reemplazo:

```
echo preg_replace( '/\*(.*?)\*/'
                 , '<b>$1</b>'
                 , 'Texto *con* y sin *negritas*'
                 ).PHP_EOL;
```

Resultado:

```
Texto <b>con</b> y sin <b>negritas</b>
```

Comment: Excelente justo lo es....muchas gracias